# Change page width in refined magazine/mag and news theme

Tags: pages, content-width

I am using Mag and news theme, which is a child theme of Refined Magazine. On the admin page, there seems to be no option of changing the page width. I am capable of editing php files as well, but I can't locate the place there where I should do it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the width your browser uses when displaying the page? That's probably in the CSS: use your browser's debug tools to locate the relevant class with the width on the page and then find this in the theme's stylesheet.

Comment: If it's something more complicated than that then you can always ask the theme authors.